How to disable autorun of jest test in VS code?
Every time I save a file, all the tests that are in the current project are automatically run. I want to turn off that option and run the test manually as needed.
I'm using jest (version 29.7.0) and VS code extension Jest(6.4.0) to test express web app.

have you searched the settings for test

@rioV8 yes, actually there is file named jest.config.js where is javascript code that configure the jest, but i have no clue what to enter to disable autorun. Currently, i disabled the vscode extension for testing and now run tests from terminal, which fixes the problem. But then what is the point of having Jest extension for VS Code.
